# Missing dependencies of kernel32.dll

Tags: c, windows, matlab, delphi, dll

I have a Matlab DLL that I'm relentlessly trying to call from a Delphi code. To do this I use `Loadlibrary()` and it returns error 126 'module not found'.

Thanks to Dependency Walker, I figured out that the problem could come from `kernel32.dll`. A lot of its dependencies from Windows API (as I understood) are missing or not found, as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image: dependencies]

How can I get these missing DLLs? Should I re-install something Windows-related?

Comment: no, this is not missing dependencies - `API-MS-WIN-*` of course exist. this is simply  Dependency Walker wrong handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are false positives. That output is perfectly normal. You will sometimes se that kind of thing, especially if you mix 32 bit DLL and 64 bit Dependency Walker, or vice versa.

If you want to find out for sure what is wrong use the profiling option in Dependency Walker. It can monitor the DLL loading process and give you a report about where it fails.

Based on your description the likely explanation is that you are failing to resolve dependencies on the Matlab runtime or the MSVC runtime.

Comment: MSVC runtime dll's most likely, I would suggest using Process Monitor with load image filter to see what dll it's looking for. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: You could do that. Dependency Walker will give you same the information in a more focused way.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Dependancy Walker could go beyond statically linked DLL's but guess I learned something new. Cheers...

Comment: Yeah, that profile mode is pretty useful and effective.